# How to relocate our source code from Vista running VisualSVN Server to Windows 7 running VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, version-control, source-code

I have been using VisualSVN Server without any problem on Vista.

When it is time to change everything to Windows 7, I wonder what's the best way to do that?

Is it best to "check in" all the code from all machines onto the Vista, and do an SVN Update for one machine, and then reinstall VisualSVN on Windows 7 and create another project.  Is that the best way?

Has anybody run VisualSVN Server (as well as TortoiseSVN) on Windows 7 machine and found that it is stable?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualSVN runs fine on Windows 7. I ran it on RC, and it's running well on final (both 64-bit) as well.

Comment: VisualSVN Server also runs well?

Comment: Yup. No issues at all. I'm running Server, Tortoise and Ankh, all happy on x64.